# How to limit the usage of budget in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-billing-api

I have a resource group named XYZ on which I want to apply a budget and when the budget is used, I want the resource group to be frozen, i.e. no more transactions can be done from the resource group.

If there any service in azure for the same or any code that can be run in PowerShell which stops the resource groups when their respective budgets are all used up?

Answer (score 0):

When you create or edit a budget for a subscription or resource group scope, you can configure it to call an action group. The action group can perform various actions when your budget threshold is met. Action Groups are currently only supported for subscription and resource group scopes. For more information about Action Groups, see [Create and manage action groups in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups).

For more information about using budget-based automation with action groups, see [Manage costs with Azure Budgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/cost-management-budget-scenario).